# A Black screen between android transition

Tags: java, android, transition

As the title says, my Mobile shows a Black screen between an android transition.
Here's my java main activity code:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
int h=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



}

public void a ( View view){

    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainWithButtons.class));
   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.left_out);
}
```

}

Here the java second activity:

```
public class MainWithButtons extends AppCompatActivity{
  @Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_with_buttons);

 }
}
```

left_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100%p"/>
</set>
```

left_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
<translate
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0"/>
</set>
```

When i comment the overridePendingTransition method i can open the second  activity, so the onClick is not the problem.

Comment: Asked and answered here :) good luck and keep it up! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690764/overridependingtransition-for-sliding-activities-in-and-out-smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Ummmm maybe try to wait before openning, like open later. As I saw from a quick read it's a refresh problem. You're jumping probably from less complex activity, to more complex one, that's why you need the CPU preprocessor power (Kamehamehaaaa) and assign open later. You will still have a small delay, but the calls will be asynced and and the black screen will dissapear, since the CPau will tell Android Java, I'm going to open YOU now, please prepare everything and it will prepare.

Comment: So what do you suggest i can do to solve the problem?

Comment: you have postDelayed() like this to open the new activty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay-in-android

Comment: aaand you have onUiThread() like this, you can read about them and their differances, which I don't know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123621/running-code-in-main-thread-from-another-thread

Comment: i've just tried both options and any of them works, i can't understand why

Comment: 1 second. I'm looking further

Comment: There you gp, see upcoming comment on your snswer

Comment: Now i've seen that i have to open the app, then click the button on my android phone to see all apps that are opened and then open the app again. If i do that, the app shows the second activity but i can't see the animation.

Comment: Someome had the same problem, I gave you a link upwards there