# Why is the animation not working on my application?

Tags: android, animation

Here is my .java file code

```
aboutus.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUsActivity.class);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_bottom, R.anim.anim_slide_out_top);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

And here are my animation files :

slide_in_bottom.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="350"
android:fromYDelta="100%"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

slide_out_top.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="350"
android:fromYDelta="0%"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
android:toYDelta="-100%" />
```

Where do you think i am wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690764/overridependingtransition-for-sliding-activities-in-and-out-smoothly

Comment: Yeah exactly, i referred to that before, but that doesn't help because all the things in that answer are already as per my written animations and code... So where is the error? @Arpanßløødyßadßøy

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues like this before when working with `overridePendingTransition`. The problem might be in the order in which you are calling. Try:

```
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_bottom, R.anim.anim_slide_out_top);
finish();
```

That should work. If that doesn't work, try calling `overridePendingTransition` after the `finish()`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you testing on emulator or device? Double check that animations are not turned off from Developer options on the device settings.

Comment: Checking on my own Android phone and animations not off!! Still can't figure out why they don't work